# Error: DataTables warning: table id=local_table - Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

can't fix this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#local_table')) {
      $('#local_table').DataTable().destroy();
  }

  $('#local_table').DataTable({
      retrieve: true,
      lengthChange: false,
      paging: true, // Enable pagination
      pageLength: 1500, // Set number of rows to display
      scrollY: '60vh', // Set vertical scrolling
      scrollCollapse: true, // Reduce the height of the table to fit the data

      drawCallback: function(settings) {
          var api = this.api();
          var rows = api.rows({page:'current'}).nodes();

          api.column(0, {page:'current'}).data().each(function(group, i) {
              if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0) {
                  $(rows).eq(i).addClass('dark-border');
              } else {
                  $(rows).eq(i).removeClass('dark-border');
              }
          });
      }
  });
});
```

already tried `initializeDataTable('#table-id')` still not working.

Comment: you are possibly initializing the table perhaps automatically. the code you provided should run once on page load. it's harder to tell than if you provided a full working example as a snippet that reproduces the issue.